# JSON.parse throws unexpected character error at start of line 1 of the JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, syntax-error, character

i am still relatively new to the whole JavaScript environment and i need help with parsing a JSON file into a JSON object to read the contents of the file. I have been reading a lot of other questions and documentation but so far i have not seen anything relevant to my question.

First the situation: I have a file called test.json which is supposed to be delivered from a server. But for testing purposes it is stored locally as `clusters.json`, in the same folder as my html document. Code for HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<html>
<head>
    <title>JSON THINGIE</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>A Header</h1>
    <p id="textone">sample text</p>
    <script>
        var jsonFile = "/clusters.json";
        var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonFile);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The codes executes untill `JSON.parse(jsonTest);`, then it throws this error (from mozilla debug tool):

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

**JSON File (clusters.json)**

```
{
    "occupation":{
      "employment":[
         {
            "id":1,
            "cluster_name":"Tekenaar",
            "weight":0.5,
            "similarity":0.1,
         },
         {
            "id":4,
            "cluster_name":"Tekenaar Constructeur",
            "weight":0.6,
         }
      ],
      "education":[
         {
            "id":2,
            "cluster_name":"HBO",
            "weight":1,
         },
         {
            "id":3,
            "cluster_name":"HBO",
            "weight":1,
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Appearantly the `{` opening bracket is wrong but the JSON docs state that files can be opened with `{` or `[`.

I have checked my JSON with multiple validator tools and even used a copypaste from the [JSON Example](http://json.org/example.html) page but everything gives the same error.

Also in accordance to the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42341547/json-parse-unexpected-character-at-line-1-column-1-of-the-json-data-php) question, i tried using `JSON.stringify(jsonTest)` first, but to no avail.

What could i possibly be doing wrong? Any help is appreciated since i am already spending too much time on this error. Thanks.

**Edit 1:**
It was indeed my own mistake of thinking that using a string would make the parser load the file automatically.

**Serverless Fix:**
I succeeded in loading the text from the file by using the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446447/javascript-read-local-text-file). Which i arrived at when i was searching for how to use `file://`.

Implementation of fix for future reference:

```
// URL to the file
var jsonFile = 'file:///C://Users//Daan//Projects//Temp Name//clusters.json'

function readTextFile(file) {
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (rawFile.readyState === 4) {
            if (rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0) {
                var allText = rawFile.responseText;
                // Show alert with the read text.
                alert(allText);
            }
        }
    }
    rawFile.send(null);
}

readTextFile(jsonFile);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `var jsonFile = "/clusters.json";` doesn't load the file, it just creates a string. The next line is trying to parse the string as a JSON object, which it is not. You will have to load the file somehow before trying to parse its content.

You will probably need a webserver to run your website on, if you don't have that already, and load the file using AJAX.

Comment: Is it possible to load a file without using the `XMLHttpRequest()` function?

Comment: Yeah, I believe it is. You should do something like this: `jsonFile = 'file://c:/my/dir/structure/clusters.json'`. And it only works as long as the HTML file is served from disk and the json file is on disk.

Comment: Or perhaps you can use the FileReader, see here for more info: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/. But I think that only works when the load is triggered by a user interaction like clicking on a button. I think an AJAX call will be your best bet.

Comment: Thank you @Thijs, i fixed it. I shall update the post shortly to show my fix.

Answer (score 0):

Try without the `JSON.parse(xxx)`

You can remove `var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonFile);`

JSON.parse is trying to convert your file in a JSON format which is JSON already.

Just use `jsonFile` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

From your code it looks like you are trying to give JSON.parse() a file name as a parameter.  JSON.parse() accepts a string.  You'll have to get your hands on the file contents and then pass this to JSON.parse().  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16991341/json-parse-file-path) may be helpful.

[JSON.parse() documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)