# Error: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: javascript, html, css, particles.js

While using particles.js with this JSON file, I obtain the following error:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of
>   the JSON dataparticles.js:1530:26
>       onreadystatechange particles.js:1530

Even though everything I used in my project is copied/pasted from the official particles.js github. Any idea on what could be wrong ?

```
{
    "particles": {
      "number": {
        "value": 80,
        "density": {
          "enable": true,
          "value_area": 800
        }
      },
      "color": {
        "value": "#ffffff"
      },
      "shape": {
        "type": "circle",
        "stroke": {
          "width": 0,
          "color": "#000000"
        },
        "polygon": {
          "nb_sides": 5
        },
        "image": {
          "src": "img/github.svg",
          "width": 100,
          "height": 100
        }
      },
      "opacity": {
        "value": 0.5,
        "random": false,
        "anim": {
          "enable": false,
          "speed": 1,
          "opacity_min": 0.1,
          "sync": false
        }
      },
      "size": {
        "value": 10,
        "random": true,
        "anim": {
          "enable": false,
          "speed": 80,
          "size_min": 0.1,
          "sync": false
        }
      },
      "line_linked": {
        "enable": true,
        "distance": 300,
        "color": "#ffffff",
        "opacity": 0.4,
        "width": 2
      },
      "move": {
        "enable": true,
        "speed": 12,
        "direction": "none",
        "random": false,
        "straight": false,
        "out_mode": "out",
        "bounce": false,
        "attract": {
          "enable": false,
          "rotateX": 600,
          "rotateY": 1200
        }
      }
    },
    "interactivity": {
      "detect_on": "canvas",
      "events": {
        "onhover": {
          "enable": false,
          "mode": "repulse"
        },
        "onclick": {
          "enable": true,
          "mode": "push"
        },
        "resize": true
      },
      "modes": {
        "grab": {
          "distance": 800,
          "line_linked": {
            "opacity": 1
          }
        },
        "bubble": {
          "distance": 800,
          "size": 80,
          "duration": 2,
          "opacity": 0.8,
          "speed": 3
        },
        "repulse": {
          "distance": 400,
          "duration": 0.4
        },
        "push": {
          "particles_nb": 4
        },
        "remove": {
          "particles_nb": 2
        }
      }
    },
    "retina_detect": true
  }
```

Comment: Could be red herring. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25743994/syntaxerror-json-parse-unexpected-character-at-line-1-column-1-of-the-json-dat and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42341547/json-parse-unexpected-character-at-line-1-column-1-of-the-json-data-php.

Comment: Was I to guess, you're getting `undefined` (or similar) from your fetch function. Check for errors, and `console.log()` around until you find the undefined. The JSON you posted is valid

Comment: It's not my fetch function, I'm using a third party module (particles.js).
The error only shows when I use parcel bundler. With live-server, everything works smoothly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25743994/syntaxerror-json-parse-unexpected-character-at-line-1-column-1-of-the-json-dat)

Answer (score -1):

Incorrect file save encoding (System.Text.Encoding) The file save encoding is not same with android studio open  encoding

Comment: This is not a solution. Add a comment instead

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).